# Map generation failing with Kartograph.js

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, cartography

I am trying to generate a very simple map using kartograph.js. But some how my code is not working.

```
    <html>
<head>
     <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
     <script src="kartograph.min.js"></script>


<!---starting karograph.js-->   

    <script language="JavaScript">
function loadmap(){
var map = Kartograph.map('#map', 900, 0);

map.loadmap('map.svg', function() {
    // add layers.
        map.addLayer('countries');
        map.addLayer('depth');
        map.addLayer('trees');
        map.addLayer('crops');
        map.addLayer('rivers');
        map.addLayer('canals');
        map.addLayer('city');
        map.addLayer('states');
        map.addLayer('coast');
        map.addLayer('coast');
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad = "loadmap()">
<div id = "map">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It basically shows a blank page. I am not sure If this has to be hosted on a local server? however I setup a local server using Python but it still shows a blank page. I checked all the source file addresses and they are all right. Not sure whats happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the console in your browser's developer tools? That might provide some information to help figure out where the error is taking place.

Comment: Good Idea, I did that just now, it shows the error loadmap is not defined?